# Steps for creating pull request to keep master clean

Tags: git, pull-request

I have one Branch lets say `Feature1`.

Now I do some commit in `Feature1` and push those commits to `Feature1`.

When I create a pull request from `Feature1` to `master`, I can see some commits in pull request which are not done by me.

If I merge this , this will create commit on `master` having commits other than mine.
It doesnot look like clear to me as why my pull request showing other commits.

What is the best strategy to create clean pull request. I read few places and its mentioned that we can use `git pull --rebase`.
Now when to use rebase option?
After I commit to `Feature1` or after push to `Feature1`?

Comment: Those commits presumably didn't just magically get in the remote feature branch, someone else pushed them there.  Are you sharing this feature branch with other people?

Comment: This is my branch and no one else using it. I can see commits which are already there in master appearing in my pull request

Comment: Are you sure that you are reading the pull request correctly?  There is no way for commits to appear in your feature branch unless someone pushed them there.  Perhaps if you massively rewrote your history you might see something like this.

Comment: commits are not appearing in feature branch but they show up in pull request

Comment: Where did you branch `Feature1` off from? And was that parent branch up-to-date when you started `Feature1`?

Comment: just wanted to check what steps u follow to create a clean pull request?